# How to set a column's default value using Microsoft SMO?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-6.0, smo

I'm trying to set the default value of a non nullable bit column using Microsoft's SMO (C#) but I get an error on table creation.

Currently what I have is

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dynamicColumn.DefaultValue))
{
    column.Default = dynamicColumn.DefaultValue;
}
```

However when trying to create the table I get the following error:

One or more errors occured.

> Create failed for Table'CustomDocument.TestDef9_Data'.
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
> The default '((0))' does not exist.

I've tried ((0)), (0), and 0, and I get the same error every time.

Is there a different property I need to set on the column object or some other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it thusly (in powershell, but it's conceptually the same):

```
$t = Get-DbaDbTable -SqlInstance . -Database tempdb -Table foo;
# $t now holds a Table object
$df = $t.columns['a'].AddDefaultConstraint('DF_foo_a');
$df.Text = 0;
$df.Create();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `DefaultConstraint` property instead. Here a snippet

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dynamicColumn.DefaultValue))
{
    column.DefaultConstraint = new DefaultConstraint(table, "DF_TestDef9_Data_ColumnName");
    column.DefaultConstraint.Text = "(0)";
}
```

Comment: Property or indexer Column.DefaultContraint cannot be assigned to -- it is read only and
'DefaultConstraint' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments.

Looks like I may need to just use column.DefaultConstraintName and  column.DefaultConstraint.Text ?